# jQuery: form not submitting with $('#id').submit();, but will submit with a 'submit' button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing the problem when i submit the form by input type button here is my code :

```
<form method="POST" id="eulaForm" action="downloadPack.php?packId=<?php echo $_REQUEST['packId'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

that is my form, which looks fine to me. in that form, i put this button:

```
<input name="declineBtn" id="declineBtn" value="Decline" type="button" class="back">

        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#declineBtn').click( function() {
                        searchTxt = $('#searchText').val();
                        // ajax logic to test for what you want
                        if (searchText != '') { return chgAction(searchTxt); } else { return true;}
                    });
                });

                function chgAction(cmpText)
                {
                    if(cmpText != '')
                        {
                            $('#eulaForm').attr('action', 'searchResult.php');
                            alert("After - action = "+$("#eulaForm").attr("action"));
                            //submit the form
                            $('#eulaForm').submit();                    
                        }
                    else{
                            url = '<?php 
                                    echo basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);?>';                            
                            window.parent.location.href = url;  
                                    //parent.history.back();
                            return false;
                        }
                }


       </script>
```

and as you can see, it calls `$('#eulaForm').submit();` , but the form is not submitting (ie. the page is not refreshing). why is that?

thanks!

Comment: Please repost your code. It seems broken at the moment.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: yes i get the alert but form not submitted

Comment: can you post your html and js code in one file, then we can note the mistake.

Comment: Seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/QM3gg/1/

Comment: Few times this fails for some reason, Thats why I always submit using document.forms["<name>"].submit()

Comment: Btw, your form contains an XSS vulnerability. You may wish to untaint `packId` before using it.

Comment: Can you try `$('#eulaForm').get(0).submit()` or `document.getElementById('eulaForm').submit()` ?

Answer (score -1):

try like this:
wrap up `chgAction()` inside document ready and add `preventDefault()`

```
               $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#declineBtn').click( function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        searchTxt = $('#searchText').val();
                        // ajax logic to test for what you want
                        if (searchText != '') { return chgAction(searchTxt); } 
                       else {  return true;}
                    });


                function chgAction(cmpText)
                {
                    if(cmpText != '')
                        {
                            $('#eulaForm').attr('action', 'searchResult.php');
                            alert("After - action = "+$("#eulaForm").attr("action"));
                            //submit the form
                            $('#eulaForm').submit();   
                            return false;                 
                        }
                    else{
                            url = '<?php 
                                    echo basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);?>';                            
                            window.parent.location.href = url;  
                                    //parent.history.back();
                            return false;
                        }
                }
         });
```

Comment: Would you add an explanation as to what you have changed? That might make it useful to a wider readership, so a general debugging technique might be learnt.

Comment: @phpBud did you try this?